# Caches! What is the difference between the saveLocations() and addLocation() function?

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage, forecasting, weather

I am a beginner in Javascript and I was given a task. It's basically a weather app..
I created a page that will output the latitude, longitude, and nickname of a place based on google geolocation API. And now I want to call forecast.io to give me back the results.
What I'm supposed to do is store the latitude, longitude and nickname in the LocalStorage... when the "save location" button is clicked and save all the locations into a list so they can CLICK and get the weather information.
But then I'm given a skeleton code which I have no idea what it does. 
What is the difference between the this.AddLocation and the savelocation() function I wrote at the back. 
The only function I wrote here is the savelocation() function which will save the location to the local storage. The other functions are the skeleton code which needs to be filled.

Any explanation of what the methods in the class should do would help a lot!

The code is as below:

```
// Returns a date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".
Date.prototype.simpleDateString = function() {
    function pad(value)
    {
        return ("0" + value).slice(-2);
    }

    var dateString = this.getFullYear() + "-" + 
            pad(this.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '-' + 
            pad(this.getDate(), 2);

    return dateString;
}

// Date format required by forecast.io API.
// We always represent a date with a time of midday,
// so our choice of day isn't susceptible to time zone errors.
Date.prototype.forecastDateString = function() {
    return this.simpleDateString() + "T12:00:00";
}


// Code for LocationWeatherCache class and other shared code.

// Prefix to use for Local Storage.  You may change this.
var APP_PREFIX = "weatherApp";

function LocationWeatherCache()
{
    // Private attributes:

    var locations = [];
    var callbacks = {};

    // Public methods:

    // Returns the number of locations stored in the cache.
    //
    this.length = function() {
    };

    // Returns the location object for a given index.
    // Indexes begin at zero.
    //
    this.locationAtIndex = function(index) {
    };

    // Given a latitude, longitude and nickname, this method saves a 
    // new location into the cache.  It will have an empty 'forecasts'
    // property.  Returns the index of the added location.
    //
    this.addLocation = function(latitude, longitude, nickname)
    {
    }

    // Removes the saved location at the given index.
    // 
    this.removeLocationAtIndex = function(index)
    {
    }

    // This method is used by JSON.stringify() to serialise this class.
    // Note that the callbacks attribute is only meaningful while there 
    // are active web service requests and so doesn't need to be saved.
    //
    this.toJSON = function() {
    };

    // Given a public-data-only version of the class (such as from
    // local storage), this method will initialise the current
    // instance to match that version.
    //
    this.initialiseFromPDO = function(locationWeatherCachePDO) {
    };

    // Request weather for the location at the given index for the
    // specified date.  'date' should be JavaScript Date instance.
    //
    // This method doesn't return anything, but rather calls the 
    // callback function when the weather object is available. This
    // might be immediately or after some indeterminate amount of time.
    // The callback function should have two parameters.  The first
    // will be the index of the location and the second will be the 
    // weather object for that location.
    // 
    this.getWeatherAtIndexForDate = function(index, date, callback) {
    };

    // This is a callback function passed to forecast.io API calls.
    // This will be called via JSONP when the API call is loaded.
    //
    // This should invoke the recorded callback function for that
    // weather request.
    //
    this.weatherResponse = function(response) {
    };

    // Private methods:

    // Given a latitude and longitude, this method looks through all
    // the stored locations and returns the index of the location with
    // matching latitude and longitude if one exists, otherwise it
    // returns -1.
    //
    function indexForLocation(latitude, longitude)
    {
    }
}

// Restore the singleton locationWeatherCache from Local Storage.
//
function loadLocations()
{
}

// Save the singleton locationWeatherCache to Local Storage.
//
function saveLocations(nickname,latitude,longtitude){
 var locations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('APP_PREFIX')) || [];
    locations.push({nickname: nickname, latitude: latitude, longtitude:longtitude});
    localStorage.setItem('APP_PREFIX', JSON.stringify(locations));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the lecturer for this unit, I'll suggest that Stack Overflow isn't the best place to be asking questions on your assignment.  The answer to your question requires knowledge from the assignment instructions which are only available to students taking the unit.

Also, you shouldn't be posting any of your code (i.e., your solution to the problem) publicly.  As part of submitting the assignment you sign a statement saying it is your own work and you haven't shared your work with anyone.  Posting your code to Stack Overflow breaks this.  Don't do it!

I suggest you carefully read the assignment instructions and the assignment FAQ.  If you still have questions, ask on the unit forum, ask your demonstrator, or ask in a consultation or held desk session.

In answer to your question, `saveLocations()` should save the `LocationWeatherCache` instance to local storage.  The `addLocation()` method should add a new location to the `locations` array attribute of the `LocationWeatherCache` class and (as HotGirlInYourPracDoingENG1003 says) it should call `saveLocations()` to ensure this change is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

`this.addLocation` adds a location object to `var locations`. It should also call `saveLocations()` to save these changes to `localStorage`.